# ASP NET MVC Making request strange behaviour

Tags: asp.net-mvc

First of all, sorry for my bad english.

I have faced a strange problem using asp net mvc.
I have simple controller, which can execute 2 operations. The first operation is continuous  and can take a several minutes. And the other is short, and executed some seconds.
Something like this:

```
public class TestController : Controler {
    [HttpPost]
    public string Func1(long id) {
        // continuous operation
        return new ValueGetter().Get(id)
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string Func2(long id) {
        return "Abc";
    }
}
```

And from the client side i call thouse methods via jqueries post:

```
$.post(url).sucess(...);
```

The problem consists in the next: while the first operation is executed, the second operation will wait, until first is finished. 
I tried to use AsyncController as described there http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx, but the result is the same...

I have logged some application events in global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_PostMapRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        LoggerManager.Info("PostMapRequestHandler fired in global.asax");
    }

    protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        LoggerManager.Info("AcquireRequestState fired in global.asax");
    }
```

And if I for example, call the first method once, and then Immediately call the second method three times, I have the following result in the log file:

```
1.PostMapRequestHandler
2.AcquireRequestState
3.PostMapRequestHandler
4.PostMapRequestHandler
5.PostMapRequestHandler
... after first method is executed sucessfuly
6.AcquireRequestState
7.AcquireRequestState
8.AcquireRequestState
```

I use IIS 7(not express) and asp.net mvc 3

Why it happen and how I can solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question here:

[Session less MVC Controller for MVC 2 / RC](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2009/12/17/session-less-mvc-controller.aspx) (MSDN Blogs)

I hope it will help, if someone faces a similar problem.